# Angular, component to make a dynamic list with several fields inside the same form?

Tags: html, angular, forms, components

I want to make a form to create invoices.

And the users should be able to add and delete lines

Anyone know a good component or libary I can use to do this in Angular?

[image: Invoice Form]

I tried to search but dosnt seem to find any components that can do what I want.
Im sure there must be something out there

Comment: you can use FormBuiilder and write components for that oor use Angular Material, but why you asking about Node? yoou neeed backend validation?

Comment: yes let me remove NodeJS :) - sorry

Answer (score 0):

Angular form array is the best option for your requirement.
Here is the link as tutorial, you can check it out 
[Link]: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/